# Multiplication tables will not work in my code

Tags: python-3.x

What is wrong with my function? I have to write a function that prints out the multiplication table for the specified number. For example: in multiTable(num) if num = 6, then the function should print:￼"see attached photo".[image]. This is python by the way. Thank you in advance for the help.

Here is my code:

```
def multiTable(num):
    empty=""
    print('\t',end='')
    for row in range(1,num):
        for column in range(1,num):
            empty = empty + (str(row*column) +'\t') + '\n'
        print(empty)
```

Comment: change `range(1,n)` to `range(1,n+1)`

Answer (score 0):

#### Reset variable before each loop

First of all you need to reset value of `empty` variable before each inner loop

Your value should be initialized with empty string: `empty = ''`

#### range loops EXCLUISVE

To loop in given range use `num + 1` as the ending point

#### Fixed code

```
def multiTable(num):
    # Display top line
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        print('\t' + str(i), end='')
    print()

    # Show mutiplication table
    for row in range(1, num + 1):
        # Start by multiplier on the left
        empty = str(row) + '\t'
        for column in range(1, num + 1):
            empty = empty + str(row * column) + '\t'
        print(empty)
```